# DDE Client From IIS

Tags: rest, iis, dde

I have deployed my API on IIS it will connect with IQLink exe using DDE when I requested a USDCAD rate from IQLink it is throwing exception even locally every thing work fine.

The client failed to request "IQLINK|USDCAD!BID".

2024-03-26 05:38:50.074 -04:00 [INF] Requesting rate again

2024-03-26 05:40:51.073 -04:00 [ERR] The client failed to request "IQLINK|USDCAD.COMP!BID".

2024-03-26 05:40:51.076 -04:00 [INF] Client in GetNewDDEObject False

2024-03-26 05:40:51.077 -04:00 [INF] TEmp is Connected or  not    True

2024-03-26 05:40:51.077 -04:00 [INF] Request item in Get Rate Call is  USDCAD.COMP

2024-03-26 05:40:51.077 -04:00 [INF] Client Service  is IQLINK
2024-03-26 05:40:51.077 -04:00 [INF] Client is  Connected  True
2024-03-26 05:41:45.039 -04:00 [ERR] Exception is NDde.DdeException: The client failed to request "IQLINK|USDCAD!ASK". ---> NDde.Foundation.DdemlException: The client failed to request "IQLINK|USDCAD!ASK".

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)

at NDde.Advanced.DdeContext.DdeThread.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)

at NDde.Advanced.DdeContext.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)

at NDde.Advanced.DdeContext.Invoke(ThreadStart method)

at NDde.Client.DdeClient.Request(String item, Int32 format, Int32 timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at NDde.Client.DdeClient.Request(String item, Int32 format, Int32 timeout)
at NDde.Client.DdeClient.Request(String item, Int32 timeout)

at ECNConnector.DDEClient.GetRate(String item, String requestedItem, Boolean applyTolerance, Double tolerance) in C:\Users\Ashar.Hussain\Desktop\Distribution Layer\Distri